# Matlab - Watershed to extract lines - lost information

Tags: matlab, image-processing, watershed

[image]

I have a vein image as follow. I use watershed algorithm to extract the skeleton of the vein.

My code: (K is the original image).

```
level = graythresh(K);
BW = im2bw(K,level);
D = bwdist(~BW);
DL = watershed(D);
bgm = DL == 0;
imshow(bgm);
```

The result is:

[image]

As you can see lot of information is lost. Can anybody help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the lighting is somewhat uneven. This can be corrected using certain morphological operations. The basic idea is to compute an image that represents just the uneven lighting and subtract it, or to divide by it (which also enhances contrast). Because we want to find just the lighting, it is important to use a large enough structuring element, so that the operation examines more global properties rather than local ones.

```
%# Load image and convert to [0,1].
A = im2double(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQp1i.png'));
%# Any large (relative to objects) structuring element will do.
%# Try sizes up to about half of the image size.
se = strel('square',32);
%# Removes uneven lighting and enhances contrast.
B = imdivide(A,imclose(A,se));
%# Otsu's method works well now.
C = B > graythresh(B);
D = bwdist(~C);
DL = watershed(D);
imshow(DL==0);
```

Here are `C` (left), plus `DL==0` (center) and its overlay on the original image:

[image: Divided by closing] [image: Otsu's method] [image: Segmentation overlay]

Comment: Works well. Pictures would be nice, though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Just one quick question.
If I want to apply imopen followed by imclose should I just edit this part 

se = strel('square',32);
im_open = imopen(A,se);
B = imdivide(A,imclose(im_open,se));

Im the paper that I am reading right now, they said using this way could help much in reducing the false branches. However when I did in this way there seems to be more false branches lol. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: The image I was using is here http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/8876/testrlt.png

Comment: They are probably talking about using the opened/closed image directly, not dividing by it. See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/images/ipexwatershed.html) for more information on this technique. The idea is to make regions more homogeneous.

Comment: Try using a larger structuring element, like `64` instead of `32`. Which size works best will be determined by the size of the heterogeneous parts of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need to lower your threshold likely (lower than what Otsu's method is giving you).  And if the edge map is noisy when you lower the threshold, you should apply a 2-D Gaussian smoothing filter before you lower the threshold.  This will move the edges slightly but will clean up noise too, so it's a tradeoff.

The 2-D Gaussian can be applied doing something like

```
w=gausswin(N,Alpha)  % you'll have to play with N and alpha
K = imfilter(K,w,'same','symmetric'); % something like these options
```

Before you apply the rest of your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You are losing information because when you apply `im2bw`, you are basically converting your `uint8` image, where the pixel brightness takes a value from `intmin('uint8')==0` to `intmax('uint8')==255`, into a binary image (where only `logical` values are used). This is what entails a loss of information that you observed.
If you display the image `BW` you will see that all the elements of `K` that had a value greater than the threshold `level` turn into ones, while those ones below the threshold turn into zeros.